# Энтропия файла

Tags: c#, файлы

Интересует подсчет энтропии файла, с текстом знаю как подсчитать, а вот с файлом не получается. Может кто подсказать, как её подсчитать? Буду очень благодарен за пример.

```
        public int Count(byte[] ByteArray,int ReadByte)
        {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ByteArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ByteArray[i] == ReadByte)
            {
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        return cnt;
    }

        public double GetCondEnt(OpenFileDialog OpenFileDlg)
        {
        FileStream FileOpen = new FileStream(OpenFileDlg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] ByteArray = new byte[100];
        FileOpen.Read(ByteArray, 0, ByteArray.Length);
        int len = ByteArray.Length;
        double[,] P = new Double[len, len];
        double H = 0; // результат
        double PHi, PA, PHiA; 
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            int ReadByte = FileOpen.ReadByte();
            PA = (double)Count(ByteArray,ReadByte) / len; 
            for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++)
            {
                PHi = (double)Count(ByteArray, ByteArray[j]) / len;
                PHiA = (double)Count(ByteArray, ByteArray[j]) / (len - j);
                P[i, j] = (double)PHi * PHiA / PA;
                H += -P[i, j] * Math.Log(P[i, j], 2);
            }
        }
            return Math.Round(H, 2);
        }
```

Получается все время -бесконечность и при большом массиве зависает.

Comment: А чем файл отличается от текста? Прочтите его в память и считайте свою энтропию.

Comment: Японский бог... Вы же получается в случае файла 1МБ будете прогонять по нему свои циклы 4*1М раз... Неудивительно, что работает медленно. Если необходимо считать статистическое распределение по содержимому байтов, то можно код соптимизировать, а именно завести массив int64 count[256], каждый из элементов которого инкрементировать при нахождении в исходном файле байта с нужным значением. Из минусов подхода - при больших размеров файла массив может переполниться.

Comment: Ну это понятно, что при большом объеме там пиши пропало. Попробую пойти путем Вашего совета. Но я не понимаю, почему все время получается -бесконечность, хотя со строкой например все отлично.

Comment: Возможно, арифметика где-то хромает. Мне лично лень разбираться. Отладчик Вам в руки.

Comment: @gecube, каким это образом массив из 256 элементов переполнится?

Comment: @avp, я предложил по сути код типа:

    unsigned char byte = ReadFromFile();
    count[byte]++;

и это все в цикле. Теперь возьмем оооооочень большой файл. Понятно, что int32 брать глубо. 4ГБ нулей и мы приплыли... А теперь представьте себе sparse-файл, занимающий на винте мало места, а по факту размером мноооого. Тут уже оценки дать сложно, но, думаю, int64 должно хватить на ближайшие пару лет...

Comment: Особо не вникал, но встречный вопрос:

    PA = (double)Count(ByteArray,ReadByte) / len; 
    //...
    P[i, j] = (double)PHi * PHiA / PA;

Что будет, если Count() вернёт 0?

Comment: @gecube, работа с оооооооочень бооооооооольшим файлом существенно ограничивается временем жизни индивидуума. 

При производительности  10^10 увеличений 64-бит счетчика в секунду до его переполнения пройдет немного больше 300 лет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        UInt32[] prevpos = new UInt32[256];
        double dS = 0;          // интеграл энтропии
        UInt32 ReadBytes = 0;   //количество прочитанных байтов
        int N;          // счетчик цикла
        double Entropy = 0;     // подсчитанная энтропия
        UInt32 NumBytes;        // сколько байтов осталось прочитать до конца буфера
        UInt32 newpos = 0;
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        for (int i = 0; i < prevpos.Length; i++)
        {
            prevpos[i] = 0;
        }
        FileStream FileOpen = new FileStream(OpenFileDlg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        NumBytes = (UInt32)FileOpen.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        do
        {
            dS = 0;
            for (N = 0; N < 1024; ++N)
            {
                // Считаем - сколько байт прошло, прежде чем мы встретили buf[N] байт
                newpos = ReadBytes - prevpos[buf[N]];
                // считаем увеличение энтропии от этого байта
                dS += (newpos <= 256) ? (double)(newpos) / 256 : (double)(ReadBytes - (newpos - 256)) / ReadBytes;
                // сохраняем новую послед. позицию найденного байта buf[N]
                prevpos[buf[N]] = ReadBytes;
                ++ReadBytes;
            }
            Entropy += dS;
            // читаем очередную порцию данных
            NumBytes = (UInt32)FileOpen.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length); //256
            // пока не достигли конца файла - продолжаем считать энтропию
        } while (NumBytes != 0);
        double x = (100 * ((Entropy / ReadBytes) / 0.63));
        MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
```

Работает нормально, осталось только над точностью поработать.