# Как запустить в исполнение алгоритма на C#, в microsoft visual studio 2013, чтобы при компиляции не было ошибок?

Tags: c#

```
UInt32[] prevpos = new UInt32[256];
        double dS = 0;          // интеграл энтропии
        UInt32 ReadBytes = 0;   //количество прочитанных байтов
        int N;          // счетчик цикла
        double Entropy = 0;     // подсчитанная энтропия
        UInt32 NumBytes;        // сколько байтов осталось прочитать до конца буфера
        UInt32 newpos = 0;
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        for (int i = 0; i < prevpos.Length; i++)
        {
            prevpos[i] = 0;
        }
        FileStream FileOpen = new FileStream(OpenFileDlg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        NumBytes = (UInt32)FileOpen.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        do
        {
            dS = 0;
            for (N = 0; N < 1024; ++N)
            {
                // Считаем - сколько байт прошло, прежде чем мы встретили buf[N] байт
                newpos = ReadBytes - prevpos[buf[N]];
                // считаем увеличение энтропии от этого байта
                dS += (newpos <= 256) ? (double)(newpos) / 256 : (double)(ReadBytes - (newpos - 256)) / ReadBytes;
                // сохраняем новую послед. позицию найденного байта buf[N]
                prevpos[buf[N]] = ReadBytes;
                ++ReadBytes;
            }
            Entropy += dS;
            // читаем очередную порцию данных
            NumBytes = (UInt32)FileOpen.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length); //256
            // пока не достигли конца файла - продолжаем считать энтропию
        } while (NumBytes != 0);
        double x = (100 * ((Entropy / ReadBytes) / 0.63));
        MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
```

Источник : [Энтропия файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/158371/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)
Покажите пожалуйста видео Youtube.

Comment: _Покажите пожалуйста видео Youtube._ — Держите: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oiXZ_aWyTY

Answer (score 1):

Наверно требуется добавить ссылку на сборку System.Windows.Forms.
И в место OpenFileDlg.FileName вписать полный путь до файла.

В общем я не экстрасенс, я не могу узнать какие у вас ошибки при компиляции проекта. Вы бы выложили ошибки компиляции сюда.